# jQuery and Smarty function escape double quotes

Tags: jquery, smarty

Smarty generate radios that uses double quotes how to escape output in jquery?

```
jQuery("#append2").html("<td>{html_radios name='stype' options=$stype selected=1 labels=false}");
```

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Does the following escape not work?

```
jQuery("#append2").html("<td>{html_radios name=\"stype\" options=$stype selected=1 labels=false}");
```

Comment: it is not a problem escaping here the problem is when smarty function generates radios: <input name="stype" value="1" <- here is double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

```
jQuery("#append2").html("{literal}<td>{html_radios name=\"stype\" options=$stype selected=1 labels=false}{/literal}");
```

[Literal documentation](http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.function.literal)